# Extending the single parity check code

Tags: coding-theory

I recently posted a question if it was possible to extend a code with odd minimum distance in some other way than the single parity check if you want to increment the minimum distance. This question has a similar flavor.

Given a $(k+1,k,2)_2$ single parity check code with $k>1$, is it possible to extend this to a $(k+2,k,3)_2$ code? I am pretty confident the answer is *no* but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible because the new code would be MDS. It is known that such codes do not exist for $n>k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing Benjamin Lindqvist's answer with the details of how this can be shown *in this case* from first principles. All this assuming that the codes are to be binary for larger field alphabets the claim is false.

Assume that a binary linear code $C$ of length $n=k+2$, dimension $k$ and minimum distance $d\ge3$ exists. The code is defined by two check equations, so its parity check matrix $H$ has type $2\times n$. In particular its columns consist of two bits each, so they all are one of $\binom 0 0$, $\binom 0 1$, $\binom 1 0$, $\binom 1 1$.

Obviously $H$ cannot contain a column $\binom 0 0$. For if column $i$ were all zeros, then the code $C$ would have a word of weight one, with the sole $1$ at position $i$. Less obvious but still not difficult to see is that $H$ cannot have two equal columns. For if the columns $i$ and $j$ were equal, then the vector $x$ of weight two with ones at positions $i$ and $j$ would satisfy the equation $Hx^T=\binom 0 0$. Meaning that $x\in C$, in violation of the assumption that the minimum weight of $C$ is $\ge3$.

So all the $n$ columns of $H$ are non-zero and distinct. Therefore there can be at most three of them. In other words $3\ge n=k+2$ and $1\ge k$.

Comment: Nice but can it be modified to hold for not just linear codes?